# unable to parse a json string using JSON.parse?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to parse a json string in my code , how ever I am getting an error as below.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2.
```

here is my code that tries to parse the string. this piece of code is written in my angular project .

```
JSON.parse('{ "id": "id", "lastName": "prasanth", "firstName": "mp", "password": "bingo!!!", "passwordInHistory": "true" }'))
```

Comment: You have an unmatching closing parentheses

Comment: That extra parentheses doesn't produce the error given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's one too many parentheses at the end

try this instead:

```
JSON.parse('{ "id": "id", "lastName": "prasanth", "firstName": "mp", "password": "bingo!!!", "passwordInHistory": "true" }')
```